# In Solspace Superseach Use the ampersand as the separator like this: pie&&cheese

Tags: solspace, supersearch

In the docs if I want the search to include all of the words it says:

Use the ampersand as the separator like this: pie&&cheese.

When I use it, it defaults with a "+" not "&" so how do I change in the search form? It works in the URL (If I change manually) so this is all I need to complete.

Thanks
Guy

Comment: https://solspace.com/software/expressionengine/super_search/docs/results/#inclusive_keywords ... it searches inclusively by default..

Comment: The problem is, the URI from default is: search&artists_tags=Classical+soloist&band_price-to=&category=/ so there is a "+" in the URL but I was "&&" - so it would look like search&artists_tags=Classical&&soloist&band_price-to=&category=/

Comment: A quick comment on your issue. I initially implemented Solspace search on a large website and I was having issues similar to yours. This is not a bash against Solspace (I use other add-ons from them), but I've found that Low Search has all of the bells and whistles you're looking for. Also, Low is much more responsive when it comes to resolving issues with his add-on. I was even able to hire Low to develop a custom search extension - he turned it around in less than a day.

Answer (score 0):

Keyword searches are inclusive by default (whether or not you see the **+** or **&&**), unless disabled with the [inclusive_keywords](https://solspace.com/software/expressionengine/super_search/docs/results/#inclusive_keywords) parameter, but there isn't a way to automatically make custom field searches inclusive, aside from having the user actually type && instead of space(s).

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I see that may be where the problem is. Would using the Tags module work in any way (to achieve the same thing)?

Comment: You can inclusively search tags, yes: search form: https://solspace.com/software/expressionengine/super_search/docs/search/#tags and search results: https://solspace.com/software/expressionengine/super_search/docs/results/#tags